# Line chart: points over ticks

Tags: d3.js

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyeEpJ?editors=0010#0

Its a stacked bar chart with a line chart on top

The line chart points appear at the left side of the bar below.

How can I position the points in the line so they appear above the ticks in the x axis.

```
let dataline = d3.line()
    .x((d) => {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .y((d) =>{
        return y(d.total);
    });

let layersLineArea = chart.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'layers-lines');

let layersLine = layersLineArea.append('path')
    .data([totalData])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr('d', dataline);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a band scale, which is not suitable for a line chart.

The simplest solution is adding half the bandwidth in the line generator:

```
let dataline = d3.line()
    .x((d) => {
        return x(d.date) + x.bandwidth()/2;
    })
    .y((d) =>{
        return y(d.total);
    });
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
let keys = [];

let maxVal = [];

let dataToStack = [];
let totalData = [];

let legendKeys = ['usedInf', 'newInf'];

let w = 800;
let h = 450;

let margin = {
  top: 60,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 50,
  right: 20,
};

let width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
let height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let colors = ['#FFC400', '#FF4436', '#FFEBB6', '#FFC400', '#B4EDA0'];

let data = [{
  "one": 10,
  "two": 12,
  "three": 18,
  "four": 22,
  "five": 30,
  "six": 44,
  "seven": 125,
  "date": "2015-05-31T00:00:00"
}, {
  "one": 30,
  "two": 42,
  "three": 38,
  "four": 62,
  "five": 90,
  "six": 144,
  "seven": 295,
  "date": "2015-06-30T00:00:00"
}, {
  "one": 30,
  "two": 92,
  "three": 18,
  "four": 100,
  "five": 120,
  "six": 10,
  "seven": 310,
  "date": "2015-07-31T00:00:00"
}, ];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  dataToStack.push({
    date: data[i]['date'].toString(),
    usedInf: data[i]['one'] + data[i]['two'] + data[i]['three'],
    newInf: data[i]['four'] + data[i]['five'] + data[i]['six']
  });
  totalData.push({
    date: data[i]['date'].toString(),
    total: data[i]['seven']
  });
}

//------------------------- Stack ------------------------//

let stack = d3.stack()
  .keys(legendKeys);

let stackedSeries = stack(dataToStack);


//------------------------- Stack ------------------------//

let x = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(dataToStack.map(function(d) {
    //let date = new Date(d.date);
    return d.date;
  }))
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .padding(0.05);

let y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(stackedSeries, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, (d) => {
      return d[1];
    })
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

let svg = d3.select('.chart').append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

let chart = svg.append('g')
  .classed('graph', true)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

//------------------------- Bar Chart ------------------------//

let layersBarArea = chart.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'layers-bars');

let layersBar = layersBarArea.selectAll('.layer-bar').data(stackedSeries)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'layer-bar')
  .style('fill', (d, i) => {
    return colors[i];
  });

layersBar.selectAll('rect')
  .data((d) => {
    return d
  })

  .enter()
  .append('rect')

  .attr('height', (d, i) => {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
  })

  .attr('y', (d) => {
    return y(d[1]);
  })

  .attr('x', (d, i) => {
    return x(d.data.date)
  })

  .attr('width', x.bandwidth());

//------------------------- Bar Chart ------------------------//


//------------------------- Line Chart ------------------------//

let dataline = d3.line()
  .x((d) => {
    return x(d.date) + x.bandwidth() / 2;
  })
  .y((d) => {
    return y(d.total);
  });

let layersLineArea = chart.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'layers-lines');

let layersLine = layersLineArea.append('path')
  .data([totalData])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr('d', dataline);

//------------------------- Line Chart ------------------------//


chart.append('g')
  .classed('x axis', true)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

chart.append('g')
  .classed('y axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10));
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #00D7D2;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
```